# some text always appear to replace my form when I try to upload my file in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

[<InMemoryUploadedFile: istockphoto-147642455-612x612.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: istockphoto-157120359-612x612.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: istockphoto-160146563-612x612.jpg (image/jpeg)>]

This text above appears to replace my file field when I click the upload button, and the form was working perfectly before and now this is happening
[Before I click the upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8npjh.png)

[After I click the upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15kIS.png)

```
#model.py
class CarImage(models.Model):
    make = models.ForeignKey(Makes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='makes')
    other_images_of_car = models.FileField(upload_to="car_images/", null=True)
```

```
# views.py
class ProductImages(forms.ModelForm):
    # other_images_of_car = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control  tick form-control-user', 'id':'formFile','multiple':True}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = CarImage
        fields =['other_images_of_car']
        widgets = {
            'other_images_of_car': forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }

@login_required    
def cars_upload_all(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product_upload_more_image = request.FILES.getlist("other_images_of_car")
        product_upload = ProductsUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        product_upload2 =ProductsUpload2(request.POST, request.FILES)
        other =others(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if product_upload.is_valid() and product_upload2.is_valid() and other.is_valid():
            car = product_upload.save(commit=False)
            car2 = product_upload2.save(commit=False)
            other2 = other.save(commit=False)
            car.owner = request.user
            car.save()
            car2.car = car
            car2.save()
            other2.others = car
            other2.save()
            for i in product_upload_more_image:
                CarImage.objects.create(make=car, other_images_of_car=i)

            messages.success(request, "Updated Successfully")
            return redirect("mobil:add")
    else:
        product_upload = ProductsUpload()
        product_upload_more_image = ProductImages()
        product_upload2 = ProductsUpload2()
        other =others()
    return render(request, "mobil/uploadcar.html", {
        "product_upload":product_upload,
        "product_upload_more_image":product_upload_more_image,
        "product_upload2": product_upload2,
        "other":other,
    })
```

This is my template file

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{product_upload}}
    {{product_upload_more_image}}
    <!-- {{product_upload2}} -->
    <!-- {{other}} -->
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

My form file is the same with the view.py

Please help!!!!!!!!!! This stuff have been given me hard times THANKS

I have removed all the attr properties I add, in the form class and widget I change from FileField to ImageField too

Comment: It might help to add your html template, and forms.py.

Comment: ok
This is my template file
` ` `
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{product_upload}}
    {{product_upload_more_image}}
    <!-- {{product_upload2}} -->
    <!-- {{other}} -->
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
` ` `

Comment: `{{product_upload_more_image}}` comes from `product_upload_more_image = ProductImages()` or `product_upload_more_image = request.FILES.getlist("other_images_of_car")`.  These are queries or lists which need to be iterated over.  There are 3 if you see your first image.